# Eclipse doesn't add asterisk for multi-line comments automatically

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

When I press enter on JavaScript multi-line comments, Eclipse doesn't add asterisk in new line automatically:

[image: Eclipse 2020-06 multi-line comments]

Autocomplete works fine on JavaScript but I don't have JavaScript on preferences (Installed Eclipse PDT):

[image: Eclipse 2020-06 preferences]

The only JavaScript I have is under *Web/Client-side JavaScript* and doesn't have any settings for comments. (Even the color template in *js* file doesn't match editor of this section).

Where is the settings to enable asterisk in new line automatically for multi-line comments?

Using:

- Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)
- Build id: 20200615-1200
- Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2020-06 uses Wild Web Developer for editing JavaScript files. As it provides no APIs for reusing that functionality, the HTML Editor relies on what's kept of the older JSDT project to support Client-side JavaScript, which is why this scenario still works there. You'll need to open a feature request at https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues if you want this behavior added.